# ¿Para qué sirve y que uso se le da a la función os.chroot?

Tags: python

Me topé con la función `os.chroot()` y bueno si entiendo que es para cambiar el root, pero me pregunto para que quiero/sirve cambiar el root, o sea, ¿qué usos se le da a esta función?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ¿Para qué sirve?

Según la documentación, la función [`os.chroot()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chroot):

> Cambia el directorio raíz del proceso actual a la ruta especificada. Disponibilidad: Unix.

Este comando lo que haces es llamar al comando `chroot(2)`:

```
$ apropos chroot
chroot (2)           - change root directory
chroot (8)           - run command or interactive shell with special root directory
ischroot (1)         - detect if running in a chroot
```

Los procesos en sistemas de tipo Unix tienen su propio Current Working Directory o Directorio Actual de Trabajo que también se le conoce como Root Directory o Directorio Raíz, al cambiar el Directorio Raíz de un proceso con `os.chroot()` lo cambias también para todos sus procesos hijos que se puedan crear.

Para ver el Directorio Raíz de un proceso puedes usar el comando `pwdx` que recibe el PID del proceso. Por ejemplo:

```
$ pgrep mysqld
1275
$ pwdx 1275
1275: /var/lib/mysql
```

A este proceso de modificar el Directorio Raíz se le conoce como "chroot jail" o "jaula chroot" ya que evita que el proceso y sus subprocesos (hijos) accedan a un nivel superior del especificado.

### ¿Qué usos tiene?

Básicamente la idea es aislar un proceso para:

- Desarrollo y pruebas
- Control de dependencias
- Separación de privilegios
- Compatibilidad
- Recuperación

### Referencias

- [Wikipedia: Chroot](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)
- [CHROOT(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html)
- [FreeBSD Handbook: Chapter 15 - Jails](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/jails.html)

Comment: Muy completa la respuesta y gracias por las referencias :)

Comment: @astrojuanlu de nada ;-)